# Infer the type of property on interface parametrically given a specifc key of that interface

Tags: typescript, generics, higher-order-functions

Given an heterogeneous interface, I would like to generate a type-safe function that operates on a given property of that interface. For example, something like this:

```
interface State {
  a: boolean;
  b: string;
  c: number;
}

// "enclose" the Interface type variable <I> so that I can generate several functions that
// operate on different properties of <I>
function createGenerator<I>() { 
  return function createOperationForProperty<K extends keyof I>(propertyName: K) {
    return function operation<T>(t: T): T {
      return calculationWith(t);
    }
  }
}
```

The returned function "createOperationForProperty" is constrained to `K extends keyof I`, so that I can only pass as `propertyName` a key that is on `I`. But `T` is unconstrained. I would like it to be the type of `I[propertyName]`. The type `I[keyof I]` would only restrict it to any type in `I`, whereas I would like it to only accept the specific type corresponding to "propertyName".

Just to finish the example, you could apply it like this:

```
const createOperation = createGenerator<State>();
const operationOnA = createOperation("a");

dispatch(operationOnA("wrongType"));
```

The hope is that this last line would fail type checking, because `State.a` is a `boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

You can require that `T extends I[K]` in `operation`, to ensure that the type of the argument matches the type of the property value on the object:

```
return function operation<T extends I[K]>(t: T): T {
```

Comment: This seems to work, thank you! However I now get an errors for the returned functions: `expected call-signature`, and my efforts to write typedefs for these run into problem of needing to declare the type before it can be supplied. For example, the typedef for `createOperatonForProperty` would presumably need to reference `T`, but would not be able to find `T`.

Comment: If you need `createOperationForProperty` to know the type of the value as well, you can define it there instead: `return function createOperationForProperty<K extends keyof I, T extends I[K]>(propertyName: K) {`